# Favicon storage and retrieval | Best practice

Tags: php, javascript, image

I'm trying to make my web app. a bit quicker.  Each page has about 20 to 200 images that are pulled of the web..they are favicons actually and the line of code below works well for me.

```
var google_favicon = 'http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=' + domain;
```

I could of course download them and put them on my server.  Because I don't know which way is best practice I just pull them off the web.

However, I'd like to do it the best way, which to me means the fastest.  Is there an answer or does it depend on such things as the quality of your hosting provider?

Thanks

Comment: other things to consider are such as how often are the images likely to change, size of file, target audiance. As well as cacheing them on the server they could be cached on the client side too. IMO if they are favicons, I doubt they will change often and they will be pretty small file size, put them on your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends quite a bit on how fast/reliable the sites serving the content are vs. how fast your server is.  Many high-traffic sites use a Content Delivery Network (CDN, e.g. Akamai) to serve their static content because CDNs have servers located in many areas and can typically get the content to the user more quickly.

My guess is that these favicons are hosted by many different providers, which means that the 'uptime' of your site (as defined by all of the content loading properly) is going to be the lowest common denominator of the uptime of all of the sites that host your images.

You also need to consider that since you don't control the sites that host these images, they could move/remove them at any time and then they would be broken.

How often do you change the images on your site?  If it's not that often and you are concerned about uptime/performance, I'd probably try to serve them all from a host that you control, whether that's your own machine or something else.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the question and gave a more general answer about hosting static content.  Since these are favicons (not random images) and they are hosted by Google then it probably is not a bad idea to let Google serve the images up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly how you are using them, but if you are wanting to optimize you site, one thing to at least consider would be to put them all into a single image file (much like a sprite would be stored) and via css pull the individual image.

Instead of having the client make 200+ requests, it would only make one for all favicons.

Answer (score 1):

To the user, it probably doesn't really matter if the images are hosted on your server, or elsewhere. When the browser sees `<img src=...>` it makes an HTTP request to GET that image.  Now unless you *know* that your hosting provider is much faster than the original web source of the image, I would say it's not worth the hassle.

Especially considering this is Google we're talking about, they are probably going to be much more available than your site could ever hope to be! (Geographic locality, ISP bandwidth, etc) Also, if the site's favicon changes, you don't need to worry about it, only Google does.

Comment: I could build a tool that collects the needed favicons and creates a sprite on the server.  I'm guessing this has been done as I see giant sheets of favicons on a google images search

Comment: That's a very could point. I totally overlooked making a sprite. Yes, that would certainly be a large performance improvement, IMO, as it is only one GET request then.